# Creating an Entity Framework code first w/join table specifying join table schema?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When using code first to create a many to many set of tables the auto created join table is automatically created in the dbo schema but I need to have it in the same schema as the tables that I am creating.

Is there a way to specify that the join tables be created in a specific Schema?

Comment: I know one way but you might not like it. Do not specify any relationship between the 2 tables. Create the jonction table manually (without foreign key implicated). Now entity won't know what you'r doing, but you do. You can add code to retrieve and validate everything. But keep in mind that lambda function aren't going to work too well, unless your good at making them from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if I specify the many to many using fluent syntax in OnModelCreating I can specify the join table schema with the ToTable("tableName","schemaName") method.